# Building a confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, econometrics

How do I know when to use the +/- alpha/2 and when do I use the alpha/2 on one end and 1-(alpha/2) on the other end when building a confidence interval?

Does it depend on the distribution the estimator follows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing $\alpha$ with $Z$ (in case of a CI derived from a normal distribution). $\alpha$ is fixed (for ex. 0.05), and it's the boundaries based on $Z$ that change. So for a standard 95 % CI you would use the values $[Z_{\alpha/2},Z_{1-\alpha/2}]$ to construct the CI, that is $[Z_{0.025},Z_{0.975}]$ in your case.

This does depend on the distribution, however the normal approximation is by far the most used.